# How to change Icon when holding mouse over

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

I have two svg icons, and i want to change from one to another in html when holding mouse pointer over, but am i quite new with icons, can somebody help?

I want to make the white icon become black when pointing at it with my mouse.
I am trying to make a "setting icon" with a link ;)

I have the svg code here:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="navigation" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="56px" height="532px" viewBox="0 0 56 532" style="enable-background:new 0 0 56 532;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: #393B3D;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: #7B7C7D;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: #767879;
    }

  </style>

  <g id="settings-on_1_">
    <path class="st0" d="M53,96h-1.2c-0.3-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.5-3.5l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4l-1.4-1.4c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0l-0.9,0.9
        c-1-0.7-2.2-1.2-3.5-1.5V87c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-2c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v1.2c-1.3,0.3-2.5,0.8-3.5,1.5l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0
        l-1.4,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l0.9,0.9c-0.7,1-1.2,2.2-1.5,3.5H31c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v2c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.2
        c0.3,1.3,0.8,2.5,1.5,3.5l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l0.9-0.9c1,0.7,2.2,1.2,3.5,1.5v1.2
        c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h2c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-1.2c1.3-0.3,2.5-0.8,3.5-1.5l0.9,0.9c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4
        l-0.9-0.9c0.7-1,1.2-2.2,1.5-3.5H53c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-2C54,96.4,53.6,96,53,96z M42,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6
        S45.3,104,42,104z"></path>
  </g>
  <g id="settings_1_">
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M16,110h-4c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-1.5c-0.6-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.6-0.7l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-1,0.4-1.4,0L4.2,105
            c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l0.9-0.9c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.7-1.6H3c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h1.5c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.7-1.6
            l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l2.7-3c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.3l0,0c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.3l0.9,0.9c0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6-0.7V87
            c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1.5c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.7l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0l2.8,2.8c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4
            l-0.9,0.9c0.3,0.5,0.5,1.1,0.7,1.6H25c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v4c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1h-1.5c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.7,1.6l0.9,0.9
            c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4l-2.8,2.8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3l0,0c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-0.9-0.9c-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.5-1.6,0.7v1.5
            C17,109.6,16.6,110,16,110z M13,108h2v-1.2c0-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.8-1c0.9-0.2,1.7-0.5,2.5-1c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.2,1.2,0.1l0.8,0.8l1.4-1.4
            l-0.8-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.8-0.1-1.2c0.5-0.8,0.8-1.6,1-2.5c0.1-0.5,0.5-0.8,1-0.8H24v-2h-1.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.3-1-0.8
            c-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.7-1-2.5c-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.9,0.1-1.2l0.8-0.8l-1.4-1.4l-0.8,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.4-1.2,0.1c-0.8-0.5-1.6-0.8-2.5-1
            c-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.5-0.8-1V88h-2v1.2c0,0.5-0.3,0.9-0.8,1c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.5-2.5,1c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.2-0.1l-0.8-0.8l-1.4,1.4
            l0.8,0.8c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1,1.2c-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.6-1,2.5c-0.1,0.5-0.5,0.8-1,0.8H4v2h1.2c0.5,0,0.9,0.3,1,0.8
            c0.2,0.9,0.5,1.7,1,2.5c0.2,0.4,0.2,0.9-0.1,1.2l-0.8,0.8l1.4,1.4l0.8-0.8c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.1c0.8,0.5,1.6,0.8,2.5,1
            c0.5,0.1,0.8,0.5,0.8,1V108z"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M14,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6S17.3,104,14,104z M14,94c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4s4-1.8,4-4
            S16.2,94,14,94z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: First of all you will have to split your icons it 2 differents `svg`. When it's done, please update your question and I will help you.

Comment: ^ … or, make two icons in a `<defs>` section and reference them with `<use>`, and change which one is displayed depending on the SVG's (or parent's) `:hover` state.

Comment: Yes ok but it's not a best practice to mix 2 svgs for this purpose. I really don't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

I've putted the icons in a defs element. Also since the elements, as you draw them, have a different position on the svg canvas, I'm translaling them back to the same position. I'm using the first icon with a `<use>` element. Next I'm using javascript in order to change the value of the `xlink:href` on mouseover and mouseleaave. I hope it helps

```js
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

navigation.addEventListener("mouseover",(e)=>{
  elUse.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#settings_on_1_');
})

navigation.addEventListener("mouseleave",(e)=>{
  elUse.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#settings_1_');
})
```

```css
body{background:white;}
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="navigation" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="56px"  viewBox="0 0 24 24"  >
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: #393B3D;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: #7B7C7D;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: #767879;
    }

  </style>
<defs>
  <g id="settings_on_1_" transform="translate(-30,-86)">
    <path class="st0" d="M53,96h-1.2c-0.3-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.5-3.5l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4l-1.4-1.4c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0l-0.9,0.9
        c-1-0.7-2.2-1.2-3.5-1.5V87c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-2c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v1.2c-1.3,0.3-2.5,0.8-3.5,1.5l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0
        l-1.4,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l0.9,0.9c-0.7,1-1.2,2.2-1.5,3.5H31c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v2c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.2
        c0.3,1.3,0.8,2.5,1.5,3.5l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l0.9-0.9c1,0.7,2.2,1.2,3.5,1.5v1.2
        c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h2c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-1.2c1.3-0.3,2.5-0.8,3.5-1.5l0.9,0.9c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4
        l-0.9-0.9c0.7-1,1.2-2.2,1.5-3.5H53c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-2C54,96.4,53.6,96,53,96z M42,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6
        S45.3,104,42,104z"></path>
  </g>
  <g id="settings_1_" transform="translate(-2,-86)">
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M16,110h-4c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-1.5c-0.6-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.6-0.7l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-1,0.4-1.4,0L4.2,105
            c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l0.9-0.9c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.7-1.6H3c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h1.5c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.7-1.6
            l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l2.7-3c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.3l0,0c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.3l0.9,0.9c0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6-0.7V87
            c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1.5c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.7l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0l2.8,2.8c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4
            l-0.9,0.9c0.3,0.5,0.5,1.1,0.7,1.6H25c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v4c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1h-1.5c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.7,1.6l0.9,0.9
            c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4l-2.8,2.8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3l0,0c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-0.9-0.9c-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.5-1.6,0.7v1.5
            C17,109.6,16.6,110,16,110z M13,108h2v-1.2c0-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.8-1c0.9-0.2,1.7-0.5,2.5-1c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.2,1.2,0.1l0.8,0.8l1.4-1.4
            l-0.8-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.8-0.1-1.2c0.5-0.8,0.8-1.6,1-2.5c0.1-0.5,0.5-0.8,1-0.8H24v-2h-1.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.3-1-0.8
            c-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.7-1-2.5c-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.9,0.1-1.2l0.8-0.8l-1.4-1.4l-0.8,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.4-1.2,0.1c-0.8-0.5-1.6-0.8-2.5-1
            c-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.5-0.8-1V88h-2v1.2c0,0.5-0.3,0.9-0.8,1c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.5-2.5,1c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.2-0.1l-0.8-0.8l-1.4,1.4
            l0.8,0.8c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1,1.2c-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.6-1,2.5c-0.1,0.5-0.5,0.8-1,0.8H4v2h1.2c0.5,0,0.9,0.3,1,0.8
            c0.2,0.9,0.5,1.7,1,2.5c0.2,0.4,0.2,0.9-0.1,1.2l-0.8,0.8l1.4,1.4l0.8-0.8c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.1c0.8,0.5,1.6,0.8,2.5,1
            c0.5,0.1,0.8,0.5,0.8,1V108z"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M14,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6S17.3,104,14,104z M14,94c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4s4-1.8,4-4
            S16.2,94,14,94z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
  </defs>
  
  <use id="elUse" xlink:href="#settings_1_" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one svg, and then use `svg:hover` and the color you want it to show when you point the mouse over it.

```
svg:hover {
  fill: red/black/...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover)

Please refer to above example and pass your image dynamically !!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img onmouseover="changeImg(this)" id="myImage" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="62" height="62">

<p>On Image hover Example</p>

<script>

var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

function changeImg(x) {
  image.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_1280.png";
}

function normalImg(x) {
 image.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please try to change to **SVG** i have done for the PNG .

Step to Do.

1. Try to implement onHover Event
2. Implement two function onHover and normal Function
3. Now Add permanent Image to Normal Function by getting Id using document.getElementById('myImage')
4. Same do for the other image

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="navigation" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="56px" height="532px" viewBox="0 0 56 532" style="enable-background:new 0 0 56 532;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: #393B3D;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: #7B7C7D;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: #767879;
    }

  </style>

  <g id="settings-on_1_">
    <path class="st0" d="M53,96h-1.2c-0.3-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.5-3.5l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4l-1.4-1.4c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0l-0.9,0.9
        c-1-0.7-2.2-1.2-3.5-1.5V87c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-2c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v1.2c-1.3,0.3-2.5,0.8-3.5,1.5l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0
        l-1.4,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l0.9,0.9c-0.7,1-1.2,2.2-1.5,3.5H31c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v2c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.2
        c0.3,1.3,0.8,2.5,1.5,3.5l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l0.9-0.9c1,0.7,2.2,1.2,3.5,1.5v1.2
        c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h2c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-1.2c1.3-0.3,2.5-0.8,3.5-1.5l0.9,0.9c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4
        l-0.9-0.9c0.7-1,1.2-2.2,1.5-3.5H53c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-2C54,96.4,53.6,96,53,96z M42,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6
        S45.3,104,42,104z"></path>
  </g>
  <g id="settings_1_">
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M16,110h-4c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-1.5c-0.6-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.6-0.7l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-1,0.4-1.4,0L4.2,105
            c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l0.9-0.9c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.7-1.6H3c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h1.5c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.7-1.6
            l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l2.7-3c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.3l0,0c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.3l0.9,0.9c0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6-0.7V87
            c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1.5c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.7l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0l2.8,2.8c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4
            l-0.9,0.9c0.3,0.5,0.5,1.1,0.7,1.6H25c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v4c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1h-1.5c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.7,1.6l0.9,0.9
            c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4l-2.8,2.8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3l0,0c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-0.9-0.9c-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.5-1.6,0.7v1.5
            C17,109.6,16.6,110,16,110z M13,108h2v-1.2c0-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.8-1c0.9-0.2,1.7-0.5,2.5-1c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.2,1.2,0.1l0.8,0.8l1.4-1.4
            l-0.8-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.8-0.1-1.2c0.5-0.8,0.8-1.6,1-2.5c0.1-0.5,0.5-0.8,1-0.8H24v-2h-1.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.3-1-0.8
            c-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.7-1-2.5c-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.9,0.1-1.2l0.8-0.8l-1.4-1.4l-0.8,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.4-1.2,0.1c-0.8-0.5-1.6-0.8-2.5-1
            c-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.5-0.8-1V88h-2v1.2c0,0.5-0.3,0.9-0.8,1c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.5-2.5,1c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.2-0.1l-0.8-0.8l-1.4,1.4
            l0.8,0.8c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1,1.2c-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.6-1,2.5c-0.1,0.5-0.5,0.8-1,0.8H4v2h1.2c0.5,0,0.9,0.3,1,0.8
            c0.2,0.9,0.5,1.7,1,2.5c0.2,0.4,0.2,0.9-0.1,1.2l-0.8,0.8l1.4,1.4l0.8-0.8c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.1c0.8,0.5,1.6,0.8,2.5,1
            c0.5,0.1,0.8,0.5,0.8,1V108z"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M14,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6S17.3,104,14,104z M14,94c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4s4-1.8,4-4
            S16.2,94,14,94z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the new code you asked for "johannchopin" setting_1_

````
 <style type="text/css">

 </style>

 <g id="settings_1_" transform="translate(-2,-86)">
   <g>
     <path class="st0" d="M16,110h-4c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-1.5c-0.6-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.6-0.7l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-1,0.4-1.4,0L4.2,105             c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l0.9-0.9c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.7-1.6H3c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h1.5c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.7-1.6             l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l2.7-3c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.3l0,0c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.3l0.9,0.9c0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6-0.7V87             c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1.5c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.7l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0l2.8,2.8c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4             l-0.9,0.9c0.3,0.5,0.5,1.1,0.7,1.6H25c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v4c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1h-1.5c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.7,1.6l0.9,0.9             c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4l-2.8,2.8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3l0,0c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-0.9-0.9c-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.5-1.6,0.7v1.5             C17,109.6,16.6,110,16,110z M13,108h2v-1.2c0-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.8-1c0.9-0.2,1.7-0.5,2.5-1c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.2,1.2,0.1l0.8,0.8l1.4-1.4             l-0.8-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.8-0.1-1.2c0.5-0.8,0.8-1.6,1-2.5c0.1-0.5,0.5-0.8,1-0.8H24v-2h-1.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.3-1-0.8             c-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.7-1-2.5c-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.9,0.1-1.2l0.8-0.8l-1.4-1.4l-0.8,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.4-1.2,0.1c-0.8-0.5-1.6-0.8-2.5-1             c-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.5-0.8-1V88h-2v1.2c0,0.5-0.3,0.9-0.8,1c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.5-2.5,1c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.2-0.1l-0.8-0.8l-1.4,1.4             l0.8,0.8c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1,1.2c-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.6-1,2.5c-0.1,0.5-0.5,0.8-1,0.8H4v2h1.2c0.5,0,0.9,0.3,1,0.8             c0.2,0.9,0.5,1.7,1,2.5c0.2,0.4,0.2,0.9-0.1,1.2l-0.8,0.8l1.4,1.4l0.8-0.8c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.1c0.8,0.5,1.6,0.8,2.5,1             c0.5,0.1,0.8,0.5,0.8,1V108z"/>
   </g>
   <g>
     <path class="st0" d="M14,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6S17.3,104,14,104z M14,94c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4s4-1.8,4-4             S16.2,94,14,94z"/>
   </g>
 </g>


 <use id="elUse" xlink:href="#settings_1_"/>
</svg>  ```And here is setting_on_1.svg ```<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="navigation" x="1px" y="1px" width="27px" height="27px" viewBox="0 0 1 9,5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 56 532;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">


 <g id="settings-on_1_">
  <g transform="translate(-29,-85)" id="settings_on_1_">

   <path id="setting" d="M53,96h-1.2c-0.3-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.5-3.5l0.9-0.9c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4l-1.4-1.4c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0l-0.9,0.9         c-1-0.7-2.2-1.2-3.5-1.5V87c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-2c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v1.2c-1.3,0.3-2.5,0.8-3.5,1.5l-0.9-0.9c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0         l-1.4,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l0.9,0.9c-0.7,1-1.2,2.2-1.5,3.5H31c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v2c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.2         c0.3,1.3,0.8,2.5,1.5,3.5l-0.9,0.9c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l0.9-0.9c1,0.7,2.2,1.2,3.5,1.5v1.2         c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h2c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-1.2c1.3-0.3,2.5-0.8,3.5-1.5l0.9,0.9c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4         l-0.9-0.9c0.7-1,1.2-2.2,1.5-3.5H53c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1v-2C54,96.4,53.6,96,53,96z M42,104c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6         S45.3,104,42,104z"/>
 </g></g></svg>```
````